# How do I serialize a list of objects with System.Runtime.Serialization.Json?

Tags: c#, json

I'm trying to avoid using any third party DLLs to turn some data to JSON.

Say I have the class:

```
public class NodeData {

  public int NodeID { get; set; }
  public int ParentID { get; set; }
  public int Index { get; set; }
  public string FriendlyName { get; set; }

  public NodeData(int nodeID, int parentID, int index, string friendlyName) {
    this.NodeID = nodeID;
    this.ParentID = parentID;
    this.Index = index;
    this.FriendlyName = friendlyName;
  }
}
```

Then I use the `DataContractJsonSerializer` to turn a constructed list of `NodeData` objects to a JSON string like so:

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
DataContractJsonSerializer ds = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<NodeData>));
ds.WriteObject(ms, data);

string jsonString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());
ms.Close();
```

This throws a `System.Runtime.Serialization.InvalidDataContractException`:

> Type 'xxx.xxx.NodeData' cannot be serialized. Consider marking it
>   with the DataContractAttribute attribute, and marking all of its
>   members you want serialized with the DataMemberAttribute attribute. 
>   If the type is a collection, consider marking it with the
>   CollectionDataContractAttribute.  See the Microsoft .NET Framework
>   documentation for other supported types

How would I make my list valid for serialization to JSON with System.Runtime.Serialization.Json?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error message states, add the DataContract and DataMethod attributes.

```
[DataContract]  
public class NodeData {
  [DataMember]
  public int NodeID { get; set; }
  [DataMember]
  public int ParentID { get; set; }
  [DataMember]
  public int Index { get; set; }
  [DataMember]
  public string FriendlyName { get; set; }

  public NodeData(int nodeID, int parentID, int index, string friendlyName) {
    this.NodeID = nodeID;
    this.ParentID = parentID;
    this.Index = index;
    this.FriendlyName = friendlyName;
  }
}
```

These attributes are what help the framework know how to serialize the objects.